R is installed but won't run
Issue: R doesn't run (see details below), even after reinstalling.
Setup:

OS: Linux Mint 21.3.
R version: 4.4.2 (2024-10-31) -- "Pile of Leaves"
RStudio version: 2024.09.1+394

Installed R from https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ using sudo apt install r-base r-base-dev.
which R returns /usr/bin/R, which is also in my PATH variable.
I have tried:

Starting RStudio (from both terminal and start menu).


Expected behaviour: RStudio launches.
Outcome: Popup with "R not found, Could not locate an R installation on the system," and the following output in the terminal:

$ rstudio
[15541:1106/115944.365680:ERROR:gl_factory.cc(120)] Requested GL implementation (gl=none,angle=none) not found in allowed implementations: [(gl=egl-angle,angle=default),(gl=egl-gles2,angle=none)].
[15541:1106/115944.367407:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(198)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[15575:1106/115944.621120:ERROR:gl_factory.cc(120)] Requested GL implementation (gl=none,angle=none) not found in allowed implementations: [(gl=egl-angle,angle=default),(gl=egl-gles2,angle=none)].
[15575:1106/115944.621981:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(198)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization


Launch interactive R session (R or R --interactive in the terminal).


Expected behaviour: Interactive R session starts.
Outcome: Nothing. New prompt appears without any output or other reaction.

I have also tried apt purge-ing and reinstalling all R-related packages and RStudio, but that hasn't changed anything.

I hope it is the Linux distribution of R and R Studio you are trying to install.

try following these install instructions

Thanks @Till, but that didn't change anything :|
